# Introduzca valor del parámetro

Tags: ms-access, sql

Tengo una consulta en la cual tiene los siguientes campos:

> Proyecto, Tiempo y HorasTotales

Cada proyecto tiene un tiempo en minutos, agrupado por suma. A esto, hay que añadirle un nuevo campo que convierta esos minutos en horas. Para ello añadí esto:

```
HorasTotales: [SumaDeTIEMPO]/60
```

Al ejecutar la consulta, me sale un cuadradito así:

[image: valor]

Le doy a aceptar y funciona perfectamente, pero claro, lo suyo es que se ejecute y ya, sin que salga esto. No sé a qué se debe.

Este es el código SQL de la consulta

```
SELECT dbo_Control_Tareas.PROYECTO, Sum(dbo_Control_Tareas.TIEMPO) AS SumaDeTIEMPO, [SumaDeTIEMPO]/60 AS HorasTotales
FROM dbo_Control_Tareas LEFT JOIN dbo_Personal_LPD ON 
GROUP BY dbo_Control_Tareas.PROYECTO, [SumaDeTIEMPO]/60;
```

Comment: Eso es que en la consulta tienes establecido un criterio (parámetro). Mírate [este enlace](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/usar-par%C3%A1metros-para-solicitar-informaci%C3%B3n-al-iniciar-una-consulta-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed).

Comment: Pero el código lo puse donde el campo, no en la zona de Criterios

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código SQL de tu consulta? A ver cómo lo tienes configurado, pero está claro que no te está reconociendo el campo.

Comment: Perdona la tardanza @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Ya puse el código en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás metiendo un campo calculado también el GROUP, y eso no debería ír ahí. Además, para pasarlo a horas, tienes que pasar a horas el individual (`dbo_Control_Tareas.TIEMPO`) y crear un nuevo sumatorio.

Yo he hecho un ejemplo muy sencillo inventándome datos:

Tabla dbo_Control_Tareas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla dbo_Personal_LPD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi consulta en la que agrupo por proyecto, calculo el tiempo, y lo paso a horas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, la consulta funciona. el SQL de mi consulta es:

```
SELECT dbo_Control_Tareas.PROYECTO, Sum(dbo_Control_Tareas.Tiempo) AS SumaDeTiempo, Sum([Tiempo]/60) AS Horas_Totales
FROM dbo_Control_Tareas LEFT JOIN dbo_Personal_LPD ON dbo_Control_Tareas.Matricula = dbo_Personal_LPD.Id_puerta
GROUP BY dbo_Control_Tareas.PROYECTO;
```

Fíjate que el campo `Horas_totales` para hacer el cálculo llama al campo `dbo_Control_Tareas.Tiempo`, no al sumatorio de éste. Así que creo que tu código debería ser algo parecido al mío.

Quita `SumaDeTIEMPO/60` de la cláusula GROUP BY, y prueba reemplazando `SumaDeTIEMPO/60 AS HorasTotales` por `Sum([Tiempo]/60) AS Horas_Totales`.

Fíjate en mi código SQL a ver si consigues que funcione y nos cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como describe la [documentación](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/usar-par%C3%A1metros-para-solicitar-informaci%C3%B3n-al-iniciar-una-consulta-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed) de Access, cualquier elemento dentro del `WHERE` engloblado por corchetes ([]) será considerado un parámetro de la consulta.

Tu consulta debería evitar los corchetes de `[SumaDeTIEMPO]` y dejarlo sin ellos

```
SELECT dbo_Control_Tareas.PROYECTO, Sum(dbo_Control_Tareas.TIEMPO) AS SumaDeTIEMPO, SumaDeTIEMPO/60 AS HorasTotales
FROM dbo_Control_Tareas 
LEFT JOIN dbo_Personal_LPD ON 
GROUP BY dbo_Control_Tareas.PROYECTO, SumaDeTIEMPO/60;
```

Comment: He aplicado esto, pero sigue saliéndome el cuadro de introducir un valor

Comment: Revisa la sentencia pues al `LEFT JOIN` le faltan los campos que lo definen. `LEFT JOIN dbo_Personal_LPD ON dbo_Personal_LPD.XXX = dbo_Control_Tareas.XXX`

Comment: Tiene, es solo que he reducido el código aquí con otros campos. `LEFT JOIN dbo_Personal_LPD ON dbo_Control_Tareas.MATRICULA = dbo_Personal_LPD.IdPuerta`